# Simple PixelGrid where I can draw big pixels (choose resolution) with the mouse?

Tags: java, matrix, grid, awt, draw

I'm looking for a way in Java to make a simple grid which fills up pixels if u drag the mouse. So just a simple drawing surface...

Now it is important that I can choose the resolution or in other words choose the pixelsize...

I need the drawings made in the grid as input patterns in a neural network. So i want to retrieve the information later on in a 2Darray.

for example: a 20*20 grid where each "pixel" (or square is maybe more appropriate) is actually a square of lets say 10*10 real pixels.

How to make a simple PixelGrid where I can draw big pixels (choose resolution) with the mouse?

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a 2D array of `boolean` (for storing the selected areas or pixels), default to false for all array elements.
2. Add a [`MouseMotionListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseMotionListener.html) to a custom painting surface.
3. The painting surface might be

   - an extended `JPanel`, or..
   - `BufferedImage` displayed in a `JLabel`
4. In the [`mouseDragged(MouseEvent)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseMotionListener.html#mouseDragged%28java.awt.event.MouseEvent%29) method, decide what 'pixel' that translates to, and set it to `true`.
5. Either call `repaint()` on the panel, or update the image and repaint the label.
6. When painting, change the color the corresponding area of every `true` array element.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your help! I thought someone probably already made a grid Class like the one I wanted, but instead of waiting I took your advice and started coding myself following your lines.

If you would just like to execute and take a look at the code. I still have a small problem with the dragMouse-action it's always filling the square right above the one i wanted. Why is this? Also please tell me if I did something strange or unnecessary in the code. Thank you again.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class GridBox extends JPanel implements MouseMotionListener {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    //The Array with the Rectangles
    private static List<List<DrawnRectangle>> pixels = new ArrayList<List<DrawnRectangle>>();
    //The Frame (JComponent)
    private static JFrame f = null;

    public GridBox()
    {
        this.addMouseMotionListener(this);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 400));

        f.add(new GridBox());

        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        drawGrid((Graphics2D)g, 20, 20, 400, 400);
    }

    public static void drawGrid(Graphics g, int rowAmount, int columnAmount, int width, int height)
    {
        int pixelSizeW = width / columnAmount;
        int pixelSizeH = height / rowAmount;

        DrawnRectangle.defaultThickness = 1;

        for(int row = 0; row < rowAmount; row++)
        {
            List<DrawnRectangle> currentRow = new ArrayList<DrawnRectangle>();

            for(int column = 0; column < columnAmount; column++)
            {
                DrawnRectangle current = new DrawnRectangle( f, (row*pixelSizeW), (column*pixelSizeH), pixelSizeW, pixelSizeH);
                currentRow.add(current);
                current.paint();
            }

            pixels.add(currentRow);
        }
    }

    public void clearGrid()
    {
        for( List<DrawnRectangle> ListRect : pixels)
        {
            for( DrawnRectangle rect : ListRect)
            {
                rect.clearInterior();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e)
    {
        Point p = e.getPoint();

        for( List<DrawnRectangle> ListRect : pixels)
        {
            for( DrawnRectangle rect : ListRect)
            {
                if( rect.contains(p))
                {
                    rect.fill(Color.black);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent arg0)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: And oh Yes, u'll have to add the DrawnRectangle to the package, u can find it here: ftp://pool-108-48-22-115.washdc.fios.verizon.net/Download/DDrive/VS6%20Projects/Projects/VB6%20Projects/Java%20Converter/J2se1_4_1/j2se/src/share/test/rmi/performance/DrawnRectangle.java